# Securing files in PHP site

Tags: php, security, mime-types

I've got a site that accepts user-uploaded files (images, pdfs, word docs, etc.) then allows other users to download them.

I realize this presents a security risk, since malicious users could upload scripts etc. that masquerade as useful files.

My question is this-- is it enough to check the mime type of the file being uploaded using PHP (mime_content_type or finfo) and set the file to read only (non-executable), or must I also store the uploaded files in a directory that is outside the web root? I would think this would eliminate most of the risk from the uploaded file, but I'm not sure. Performing a virus scan on uploaded files is not possible in this situation.

Thanks for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to upload files outside the document root, and typically using randomized filenames which are then mapped to the correct item/object/post in the database.  If additional permissions are needed to access the files, make sure you check them before allowing downloads, and of course you'll have only authenticated users uploading.

Fileinfo `finfo_` is useful for validating most mimetypes, at least to verify that something called ".txt" is actually a text file and not a binary blob, or that a ".jpg" really appears to be a jpeg based on its first few or last few bytes. It may require some extra work sorting out MS Office mimetypes, as if I recall correctly, they all come out as application-msword. But you can then use the file extension to figure out what it is really supposed to be (xls, ppt, doc, etc).

A PHP script then supplies the downloaded file, rather than the web server directly serving it. For that reason, you should store the mime type along with it, so that you can serve the appropriate headers.

```
header("Content-type: application-whatever");
header("Content-length: size-of-the-file-in-bytes");
```

Comment: Hi Michael-- thanks for the tip on finfo. I'll look into that. Also, the randomized filename is something I've already implemented but forgot to mention, so that should be good.

Comment: See the Fileinfo documentation here, if you haven't already http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: Note that even content sniffing doesn't protect you against multi-purpose files - e.g. concatenating a GIF image+ZIP archive (in this order) will give you a file that will be both a valid GIF file and a valid ZIP archive (as GIF has headers up front, whereas ZIP at the end).

Answer (score 1):

I would check the mime type of the file but I wouldn't rely on this.  Even if the file is a full blown `.gif` and contains a comment in its id3 tag which is a php, it can be [executed with a local file include](http://eohnik.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/0x0144lfi-to-rce-exploit-with-perl-script/).  A safer approach would be store files in the database using a `long blob` datatype.   However this kind of overhead is crap.

**The best solution** from the perspective of security,  scalability and perforce would be to use a no-sql database like CouchDB.

A few things to keep in mind,  don't trust `$_FILES[]`.  `$_FILES['type']` could be anything the attacker wants so there is no point in checking it from a security perspective.  And `$_FILES['name']` could have nasty input like `../../../`.  Its best to rename files to the primary key and then store information about that file in a relational database (like mysql).

Comment: thanks for the tips rook-- as mentioned above, the files are being renamed to a random name, and the filename is being stored in a DB, so that's taken care of. We also move the file to a tmp directory prior to checking for mime type, then rename, chmod and move the file to the permanent storage location.

Comment: @julio cool so then your only concern would be an LFI attack. (Unless the attacker is unable to know this random file name without sql injection,  maybe that the point...)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you use every tool at your disposal to test for the file type. But know that there are other ways a hacker can implant a dangerous file.

Your best bet is to have the files be uploaded to a different **server**. One that can only host files.

Comment: yes, for my own stuff I agree, I would use Amazon S3 or something similar to handle images and files, but that is not an option in this case. I'm looking for tactics to minimize risk when you must handle uploads and serving of user-submitted files.